# How to expose an application in a kubernetes cluster in nodeport service set up?

Tags: kubernetes, shinyapps, shinyproxy

I am trying to set up a Kubernetes cluster on bare metal using a master and worker node. I have deployed a R shiny based application inside the cluster and I am attempting to access it from outside the cluster. I am a novice in this field, so I would appreciate some guidance in setting up the following:

Ingress NGINX is installed and the NodePort service is created to make this available outside the cluster.

Can you please explain how to add DNS records to this NodePort service and how to serve this application as HTTPS? I was unable to install metallb as load balancer since the server is part of the university network.

Any input regarding the addition of the DNS record and redirection of traffic to HTTPS would be appreciated.